# ListView in alphabetical order & map?

Tags: java, android

I've a ListView with many names (in scattered order) connected with related image & sound. I've put the names in an ArrayString for translation in other languages. All works fine and the translations too. But when I add a **Array.sort** for have the list in alphabetical order the problem starts... I've the correct alphabetical order but now the images & audio don't match correctly. How to do that in the easiest way? I need to use map? if yes, how to use it correctly? thanks to all.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

ListView myListView;

int [] myImages = {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4, R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6, R.drawable.a7};
int [] myContacts = {R.drawable.c1, R.drawable.c2, R.drawable.c3, R.drawable.c4, R.drawable.c5, R.drawable.c6, R.drawable.c7};
int [] myAudio = {R.raw.a1, R.raw.a2, R.raw.a3, R.raw.a4, R.raw.a5, R.raw.a6, R.raw.a7};
String [] myNames;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myListName);

    Arrays.sort(myNames);

    myListView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, myNames, myImages);

    myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("pName", myNames[i]);
            mIntent.putExtra("pImage", myImages[i]);
            mIntent.putExtra("pContact", myContacts[i]);
            mIntent.putExtra("pSound", myAudio[i]);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pojo class containing contact, images, audio and names and use collection.sort to sort Item list accordingly

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);   

Collection.sort(itemList);

Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() { 
@Override 
public int compare(Item s1, Item s2) { 
        return s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getNames());
     } 
});

myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: sorry, it's certainly a my problem, but it's not the easiest way for me... other solution?

Comment: It is easy just do some effort

Comment: I tried to make pojo class and other without any result... I don't want change my adapter code of ListView.. I think there are other ways to do it but I don't know at the moment...

Comment: The proper way is to do with pojo. Create an array list of of object and add object which contains names, contacts and images and sort the list as i mentioned above

Comment: thanks Fazal, in these day I tried to do it. but when I try to make a List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>() I can use only the String[] or the int[] and not together.. I've understand you'r solution but is difficult for me because I made my ListView from a tutorial and with your system I need to change all my Adapter code....  but with map can't doing anything good?