# Sort ListView with text, image and sound

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` with text, image and sounds. I've used an String Array for texts. images and sounds are using an int array

```
int[] = {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3, ...}
```

When I change the language of the app the the order of text list change but not the images and audio.

How can I attach the list of images to the list of text like this?  "usa"="01.jpg" , "Japan"="02.jpg", etc...

Comment: Is your string array a predefined set of strings?

Comment: share your listview class

Comment: @Abubakar is a String Array for text. This is how is my code (old question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834840/listview-in-alphabetical-order-map

Answer (score 1):

Create a data class to store related data together:

```
public class Language {

    public Language(String name, int image, int sound){
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    private final String name;
    private final int image;
    private final int sound;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int getSound() {
        return sound;
    }
}
```

And then add your items to a `List`:

```
List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<Language>();
languages.add(new Language("USA", R.drawable.a1, R.raw.s1));
languages.add(new Language("Japan", R.drawable.a2, R.raw.s2));
```

Finally use generated `List` in the `ListView`

Comment: "And then add your items to a List" ... what kind of list? array list? simple list? sorry, but I'm new to android. how to do that, please?

Comment: thanks for help, but I need an alternative approach (even if this is correct). I've my Adapter and Listview already done (from tutorial) and I would not to rewrite all the code from scratch because it would be difficult for me.

Comment: @RonnyWestwood However is easier for you, but using static arrays is not the appropriate way in most cases, good luck

Comment: sorry if I insist but with map can not do anything? this is my previous question with the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834840/listview-in-alphabetical-order-map

Comment: @RonnyWestwood If you don't want to change any code, you can never make things done, change your adapter code upon the efficient way and forget about that tutorial